# Submit form elements within a table as ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamically generated table with an edit and delete button within each row, when a user edits inputs, checkboxes, and textareas, clicks edit, I need to post values to a processing page
How to send ajax request that contains form elements that are in html table this (row) or specific row, or this iteration only row?
Please help I'm not that good at js

Comment: Create distinct forms for each row.

Answer (score -1):

```
//First of all thank you.
//After a deep search, I solved my own problem, here's the answer 
// if anyone has encountered the same thing:
<script>
$('.editRow').on('click', function (e) {
    var data = {};
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowData = row.find('input, checkbox, textarea');
    if (rowData.length > 0) {
        rowData.each(function () {
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
            //rowData.push($(this).val());
        });
        //data=dataRow
    }
    $.ajax
    ({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'tbl_process.php',
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```